# How to setup password expiration using ASP.NET Identity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET project using Identity. For Identity Configuration regarding passwords, the `PasswordValidator` is being used. How do I expand the enforcement of password beyond what `PasswordValidator` has currently (`RequiredLength`, `RequiredDigit`, etc.) to satisfy a requirement that asks for password expiration after N days?

Answer (score 23):

There is no such functionality builtin ASP.NET Identity 2. Easiest is to add a field on the user like **LastPasswordChangedDate**. And then check this field during each Authorization.

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var user = await GetUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if(user.LastPasswordChangedDate.AddDays(20) < DateTime.Now)
           // user needs to change password

    }
}
```

Comment: @RickAnd-MSFT where is the answer below?

Comment: @EricFalsken He posted an answer a year ago but it seems to be deleted. The above solution is the easiest and best way to handle password exipration. There is no such built in functionality.

Comment: at this point they're logged in. They can ignore the change password. How to force? How to log them out? So they can't do anything till they change password

Comment: @t.durden late reply, but for anyone happening upon this, you can use Middleware to check the claim and redirect to the change password screen if the claim is present. As this is in middleware, anywhere they try and go will redirect them to change password page.

Answer (score 11):

Adding on to @Rikard's answer...

I added `LastPasswordChangedDate` to my `ApplicationUser` model, like so:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Add a static configuration setting to `AccountController` (you'll need this later on in `Login()`:

```
private static readonly int PasswordExpireDays = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordExpireDays"]);
```

Then, during `Login`, check to see if the user should reset password. This only checks after a successful login, as to not bug user too much.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                    if (user.LastPasswordChangedDate.AddDays(PasswordExpireDays) < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Manage");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error: Invalid username or password");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Make sure to update the `LastPasswordChangedDate` when the user successfully updates password, in ManageController, ChangePassword action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Since you're allowing them to sign in before moving them to the change password screen, couldn't the user simply hit a different url and thus bypass changing their password?

Comment: @JohnnyFun is right. You should use `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` instead `PasswordSignInAsync` in the `Login` method to fix this issue