# Identity password expiry

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, passwords, asp.net-identity

I have identityServer4, using ASP.NET Core Identity. Password expiration and password history feature need to be implemented. I saw this issue on git, but is it still not implemented?  https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/99
Are there any new workarounds except old question like this?
[How to setup password expiration using ASP.NET Identity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039537/how-to-setup-password-expiration-using-asp-net-identity-framework)

Comment: Asking your question over on github (like you already did) seems to be the better approach.