# Add password expiry to ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC project using Identity and individual authentication.
I ask for help to add password expiry feature to my project.
I saw this answer [How to setup password expiration using ASP.NET Identity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039537/how-to-setup-password-expiration-using-asp-net-identity-framework)
but i can't make those changes because i can't find the account controller like in asp.net mvc 5.I made Identity scaffolding into my project but it just added the views.How can i customize Identity to add password expiry feature?

I just added an ApplicationUser class that extends IdentityUser and i added into ApplicationUser only one property called LastPasswordChangedDate.

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser 
{ 
   public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; } 
}
```

In Startup.cs i added the following lines:

```
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I tried to implement the solution given in the link but i can't find the AccountController in my  project.Should i implement it by myself?And if i have to implement it, should i override an existing controller?

Thanks!

Comment: That answer implements an Auth filter to check for password expiry.

Comment: Welcome to stack we are not a coding service.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question and show us what you have tried and explain any issues you are having with **your** solution.

Comment: `AccountController` no longer exists. The old Identity controller/view scaffolding has been replaced with Razor Pages within the "Default UI" Razor Class Library. As such, the Default UI is included programmatically via `AddDefaultIdentity` (which internally calls `AddDefaultUI`). If you want to modify the UI, you need to scaffold it into your project. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio